# Google Sheet to SPLIT and STRIP

Tags: google-sheets

I am splitting the content of a Google sheet cell (C2) which has the contents as below:
using `=SPLIT(C2,CHAR(10))`

```
Work Order number: 1157
Item: 0.16/50/100
Shift knots: 7700
Shift weight: 6.300
Downtime: 0
```

That will SPLIT those values into into 4 cells in C4, D4, E4, F4 and then I strip out the leading characters like below:

```
Item: from C4 using =RIGHT(C4, LEN(C4)-6), 
Shift knots: from D4 using =RIGHT(D4, LEN(D4)-13), 
Shift weight: from E4 =RIGHT(E4, LEN(E4)-14) and 
Downtime: from F4 using =RIGHT(F4, LEN(F4)-10)
```

What I would like to ask you is if there is a better way to achieve values like
`0.16/50/100, 7700, 6.300, 0` split up across cells from 1 cell? which at the moment I am doing as a 2 step process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(split(C2, char(10)), ".*:\s",))
```

and see if that helps ?

[image]

EDIT: If the data is 'horizontal', you could use the same approach but split the cell using the comma as the delimiter.

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(split(C5, ", ", 0), ".*:\s",))
```

[image]

### References:

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)

Comment: that formula worked. Have acknowledged your solution. Thank you

Comment: Is there any way to split the cell value if the data is in a horizontal way? like

`Supervisor: Name, Shift: I, Group: B, Calendar: 30/03/2021, Time: 01:51 PM, Shift Strength: 12`

Comment: Expecting the output `Name I B 30/03/2021 01:51 PM 12` in separate cells in the same row